# Can moderators "Accept" not their own answers on not their own questions?

Tags: discussion

I didn't know how to form the question properly, but here is an example to what I mean:

This question was bumped to the homepage by Community: 
[Magento showing wrong customer ip](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155918/magento-showing-wrong-customer-ip)

The question has an answer, provided by the person who asked the question so it is clear that it is the correct answer.

Can moderators "Accept" answers on questions like this so it doesn't get "bumped" and spam the "Top Question" section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators (and other trusted users) can delete accepted answers. Nobody except the asker can accept an answer.

See [this Meta.SE for why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period)

Answer (score 5):

No..........................no

Comment: Is there any way moderators can "mark" those questions so they are not getting  bumped?

Comment: No.............

Comment: Very constructive. Thanks.

Comment: Should i provide a longer explanation that just means "no" or should i just say "no"? Ok. Here it is. Only the person that asks the question can accept the answers. Moderators can close questions to not make them appear as bumped, but that would make it worse. So dhort answer... no, what you are asking it is not possible. Does this make it better? No.

Comment: Yes. It actually makes it better. "Moderators can close questions to not make them appear as bumped, but that would make it worse." is the kind of answer I was hoping for. I'm tempted to ask why it would make it worse, but I'm anxious about the feedback so let's leave it like that. Thanks.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Answer the question
Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: Closing a question that has a valid answer would be worse because "closed" means there is something wrong with the question. It will not get indexed and it will not help future readers.

Comment: @Greg, based on your comments in this thread: This seems to be a bit of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. You think you want questions to be accepted... However, if your _goal_ is to keep questions from being bumped periodically, then the solution is to upvote an answer. (If no answers are worth being upvoted, in your opinion, then please provide an answer that is worth upvoting.) When an answer is upvoted enough, its question stops being bumped.